# label linebreaking - should span across entire div

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS class named bar. My Label (Span) in the example is "Very Dissatisfied". If the width percentage is low (ie: 5%) then the Label line breaks (example: Very [linebreak] Dissatisfied) instead of spanning the entire div beyond the bar18.png graphic.

CSS:

```
.bar {
background: transparent url(bar18.png) repeat-x top left;
float: left;
clear: left;
height: 30px;
}

.bar span{
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 7px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bar" style="width:8%;">
    <span>Very Dissatisfied</span>
</div>
<div class="p">
    <span>(1) 8%</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
span{margin-left:20%}
.bar {
background: transparent url(bar18.png) repeat-x top left;
float: left;
clear: left;
height: 30px;
}

.bar span{
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 7px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```